# Why does Android call a fragment's onDestroyView when a new fragment is being added?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am wondering why the `onDestroyView` has to be called when `onDestroy` does not get called. It basically affects initializations done in `onCreateView` that requires being done only once through the fragment's entire lifecycle. There are initializations reliant on the root view created in `onCreateView` but then the initializations are not meant to be done in a case the fragment is not in view because another fragment has to be attached to the activity.

I know a property could be used in the class to check such reinitializations but that feels more like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment can go through 4 lifecycle states:

1. Initialized - instantiated and unhandled by `FragmentManager`
2. Created/Started - fragment is added to the `FragmentManager`, `onCreate` and `onStart` called
3. Resumed - fragment attached to the `FragmentManager`, `onResume` and `onCreateView` is called
4. Destroyed - fragment removed from `FragmentManager`, `onStop` and `onDestroy` is called (if fragment was still Resumed `onPause` and `onDestroyView` is called beforehand as well)

Optionally you can `Pause` the fragment by detaching it but NOT removing it from `FragmentManager`. This triggers `onPause` and `onDestroyView` and lets you move between state 2 and 3.

It's a bit confusing but used in some cases like a `ViewPager`, where you want to keep the fragment alive but free up memory of or recycle the `View` for another page while you scroll.